# Leave cell blank when other cell is not blank

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I currently have two cells in an Excel sheet:

- One which counts how many days an issue has been open using the formula:
  `=IF(ISBLANK(B2),"", DAYS360(B2,$AY$1))`
- and another cell which counts how long it took for the issue to close using the formula:
  `=IF(AU:AU="","",DAYS360(B2,AU2))`

This works great, but I've noticed when I come to refresh my data it is still counting the days of the issue being open. I need the first formula to stop working once the issue has been closed.

Please see the screenshot below. How can I fix it?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

If I understood it correctly, AY1 cell shows the current date `=TODAY()`, and when an  issue gets closed the "how long has been open" will be equal to "how long it took to close".

If you use this formula for AV2 cell, it will stop counting once you enter the "stop date" to AU2.

```
=IF(AW2="",IF(ISBLANK(B2),"",DAYS360(B2,$AY$1)),"")
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Yes that's it. The formula works. Although is there anyway of leaving AV2 blank once AW2 has been completed?

Comment: Sure, change the last 4 character of the formula: instead of ..AW2) it shall end with ..."")

Comment: I just edited the original formula in the answer, so now you can find there the proper one.

Comment: Glad it worked. You can close this question by marking this answer as "Accepted".

Answer (score 0):

`ISBLANK` returns FALSE if the cell's contents are `""` (an empty string). You can test this by setting the contents of a cell to `=""` and trying `ISBLANK` from another cell. Try using `IF(B2="", ...)` instead.

Comment: The formula currently does what I need and counts the date from when the issue was raised (in B2) and continues to count how many days its been open. Once it's closed I need it to stop counting though and that's once there is a figure in AW

Comment: Then I misunderstood your question, I think. Sorry! Do you need an `AND` condition in the first formula to check whether it's been closed? Perhaps a small screenshot would help?

Comment: It's not letting me send a screen shot or snippy tool. I basically need cell AV to stop counting days once AW has been populated

Comment: managed to attach a screen shot to my original post, hope this helps